# Error #1064 while executing sql query in phpmyadmin (wamp server)

Tags: php, mysql, database

m trying to make simple login registration app in android having php mysql db at the back end.. when i try to execute following query, i get error in phpmyadmin

Code:

```
create database android_api /** Creating Database **/

use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   id int(11' at line 3
```

also i'd like to know.. the tutorial m following says i need two machines on same wifi network to run php n android.. cant they be run on same machine?? how about after deployment??

Answer (score 1):

try the following. Creates a db to keep it out of yours for a test.

```
create schema abc123; -- create a db
use abc123; -- use it

create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime null,
   updated_at datetime null,
   unique key(unique_id),
   unique key(email)
); /** Creating Users Table **/

drop schema abc123; -- clean up drop schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
create database android_api; 

use android_api;

create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);
```